# The problem of switching the screen twice when pressing the button

Tags: ios, swift, function, uikit, storyboard

I switch between my screens using the storyboard design style. But when I press one of the buttons, it makes the transition twice, one after the other. My app is not crashing. Why might this be caused?

```
    @IBAction func showLoginViewController(_ sender: Any) {
        tmainQueue { [ self ] in
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLoginViewController", sender: nil)
        }
    }
```

[Storyboard Segue Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrpw4.png)

I was expecting it to pass 1 time on the screen transition. But he made the switch twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag the segue from the source vc to the destination vc , then you need to put this line inside the button's action

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLoginViewController", sender: nil)
```

but if you drag it from the button itself to the destination vc  , then don't create an action for the button , clicking it is sufficient for the move.